# how can i return an attribute from an xml file in xquery?

Tags: xml, xquery, xpath-2.0

i struggling to get the title of films ordering by the name of Author , what i mean by that ;i want to get the name of films of each author.
this my query :

```
    for $f in doc("Films.xml")//FILM,
$a in doc("Artistes.xml")//ARTISTE
where $a/@ID=$f/ROLES/ROLE/@acteur
order by $a/NOM
return string($f/@title)
```

the ressource :

```
<ARTISTES>
<ARTISTE ID='6'>
<NOM>Cameron</NOM>
<PRENOM>James</PRENOM>
<ANNEENAISS>1954</ANNEENAISS>
</ARTISTE>
<ARTISTE ID='3'>
<NOM>Hitchcock</NOM>
<PRENOM>Alfred</PRENOM>
<ANNEENAISS>1899</ANNEENAISS>
</ARTISTE>
</ARTISTES>



<FILMS>
<FILM titre='Vertigo'>
 <ANNEE>1958</ANNEE>
 <GENRE>Drame</GENRE>
 <PAYS>USA</PAYS>
 <MES>Hitchcock</MES>
 <ROLES>
  <ROLE acteur='3'>John Ferguson</ROLE>
  <ROLE acteur='16'>Madeleine Elster</ROLE>
 </ROLES>
</FILM>
<FILM titre='Alien'>
 <ANNEE>1979</ANNEE>
 <GENRE>Science-fiction</GENRE>
 <PAYS>USA</PAYS>
 <MES>Scott</MES>
 <ROLES>
  <ROLE acteur='6'>Ripley</ROLE>
 </ROLES>
</FILM>
<FILM titre='Titanic'>
 <ANNEE>1997</ANNEE>
 <GENRE>Drame</GENRE>
 <PAYS>USA</PAYS>
 <MES>Cameron</MES>
 <ROLES>
  <ROLE acteur='3'>Rose DeWitt Bukater</ROLE>
  <ROLE acteur='6'>Jack Dawson</ROLE>
 </ROLES>
</FILM>
</FILMS>
```

I will be thankful if there is anyone who gonna help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Should `@title` be `@titre`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller yeah bro, just an error of taping.

Comment: So, does that typo solve the problem or not?

Comment: no it gave the solution but not what i want, what i want exactly is for each author the list of the film who he is acting in it.

Answer (score 0):

First put everything into a root element.
Here's my try:

```
let $doc := doc('1.xml')
let $authors := for $i in $doc//ARTISTES/ARTISTE
  return data($i/NOM)
for $author in $authors
  for $mes in $doc//FILMS/FILM where xs:string($mes/MES) = xs:string($author)
    return <Res>{data($author), data($mes/@titre)}</Res>
```